# Bash script ввод пароля

Tags: linux, bash

Всем добрый вечер.
Запускаю bash скрипт, и для того чтобы добавить пользователя в программу, нужно ввести пароль и потом еще его повторить. Как это сделать с помощью скрипта

Comment: зависит от того как именно пароль читается... возможно хватит простого отправления его в трубу на ввод, но вероятно лучшим решением будет ознакомиться с утилитой `expect`...

Comment: Строка запрашивает пароль и потом еще раз нужно его подтвердить

Comment: это я понял, но пароль может читаться с обычного stdin'а, а может напрямую из tty-устройства

Comment: Я хочу указать пароль в самом bash скрипте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... добавить пользователя в программу ...

Если под программой понимать программу linux используя утилиту **useradd**

-p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account

Желательно, заранее сохранить хеши паролей и использовать только их в скриптах:

```
~# echo "password" | openssl passwd -1 -stdin # получите хеш пароля
~# useradd -d /home/usrname -g grpname -m -p password_hash usrname
```

Можно добавить пользователя и потом сменить пароль:

```
~# useradd -d /home/usrname -g grpname -m usrname
~# echo "password" | passwd usrname --stdin
```

Если речь идет о другой интерактивной консольной программе, которая запрашивает какие либо данные и ждет ввода то, как вам уже и советовали, можно использовать *expect* (очень деревня утилта...)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --

set pass "yourpass"

proc setpass { pass } {
    spawn your_mega_cli_cmd # Ваша программа с параметрами тут
    expect_after {
        timeout { catch { close }; wait; return 1 }
        eof { catch { close }; wait; return 1 }
    }
    expect {
        ".*assword.*" {send  "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
    }
    expect eof
}

setpass $pass

# End of script
```

Comment: Извини, может я немого неправильно задал вопрос. Покажу пример:

#!/bin/bash

apt-get install pure-ftpd pureadmin -y
pure-pw useradd joe -u ftpuser -d /home/ftpusers/joe

Команда pure=pw говорит что нужно задать пароль на пользователя, 
я хочу указать его в скрипте а не ручками вводить

Comment: @Ruslan1989 добавь в вопрос.